# How can I creating complexType variables in Coldfusion for use in SOAP request arguments?

Tags: soap, coldfusion, arcgis

### UPDATE

---

After perusing the docs some more I noticed that I left out the FieldArray and PropertyArray keys.  So I no longer get the type mismatch error, but the SOAP request is still not right.

**Here is the Error**

```
The fault returned when invoking the web service operation is:
AxisFault faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}client faultSubcode: faultString: Error processing server request faultActor: faultNode: faultDetail: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:Error processing server request at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:221) at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:128) at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087) at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) at org.apache.... ''
```

**Here is the revised Code**

```
<cfscript>
function newField(Name, Type, IsNullable, Length, Precision, Scale) {
    s=StructNew();
    s["Name"]=arguments.Name;
    s["Type"]=arguments.Type;
    s["IsNullable"]=arguments.IsNullable;
    s["Length"]=arguments.Length;
    s["Precision"]=arguments.Precision;
    s["Scale"]=arguments.Scale;
    return s;
}

function newRecord(oid, zipcode) {
    a=ArrayNew(1);
    ArrayAppend(a, arguments.oid);
    ArrayAppend(a, arguments.zipcode);
    return a;
}

function newKeyValue(key, value) {
    s=StructNew();
    s["Key"]=arguments.key;
    s["Value"]=arguments.value;
    return s;
}
</cfscript>


<cftry>

<cfscript>
ws = CreateObject("webservice", "http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/services/Locators/TA_Address_NA_10/GeocodeServer?wsdl");
recordset=StructNew();
</cfscript>

<h1>GeocodeAddresses</h1>
<cfscript>
fields=StructNew();
fields["FieldArray"]=ArrayNew(1);
ArrayAppend(fields.FieldArray, newField("oid", "esriFieldTypeOID", false, 10, 0, 0));
ArrayAppend(fields.FieldArray, newField("zipcode", "esriFieldTypeString", true, 10, 0, 0));
recordset["Fields"]=fields;

records=ArrayNew(1);
ArrayAppend(records, newRecord(1,"33607"));
ArrayAppend(records, newRecord(2,"90210"));
recordset["Records"]=records;


mappings=StructNew();
mappings["PropertyArray"]=ArrayNew(1);
ArrayAppend(mappings.PropertyArray, newKeyValue("oid", "oid"));
ArrayAppend(mappings.PropertyArray, newKeyValue("Zip", "zipcode"));

propertys=StructNew();
propertys["PropertyArray"]=ArrayNew(1);
</cfscript>

<cfscript>
result = ws.geocodeAddresses(AddressTable=recordSet, AddressFieldMapping=mappings, PropMods=JavaCast("null", ""));
</cfscript>

<cfdump var="#ws#" label="#GetCurrentTemplatePath()#" />

<cfcatch>
    <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" label="#GetCurrentTemplatePath()#" />
    <cfdump var="#GetSOAPRequest(ws)#" label="#GetCurrentTemplatePath()#" />
    <cfdump var="#GetSOAPResponse(ws)#" label="#GetCurrentTemplatePath()#" />
</cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

**Here is the SOAP XML request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <GeocodeAddresses xmlns="http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.0">
            <AddressTable xmlns="" xsi:nil="true"/>
            <AddressFieldMapping xmlns="" xsi:nil="true"/>
            <PropMods xmlns="" xsi:nil="true"/>
        </GeocodeAddresses>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It now appears that despite the contents of the structures I am passing into the request as arguments, they are being considered null by Coldfusion for building the SOAP package.

---

### ORIGINAL BELOW

---

I have a web service I am trying to access.  The problem is that the methods defined by the WSDL have complexType arguments.  In reality these complex types are actually quite simple structs and arrays, but I get the error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

**Here is the WSDL link**
http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/services/Locators/TA_Address_NA_10/GeocodeServer?wsdl

**Here is some documentation on the service**
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/soap/index.htm#SOAP_Geocode_GeocodeAddresses.htm

**Here is the code I am trying to test this with**

```
<cfscript>
function newField(Name, Type, IsNullable, Length, Precision, Scale) {
    s=StructNew();
    i=0;
    for(i in arguments){
        s[i]=arguments[i];
    }
    return s;
}

function newRecord(oid, zipcode) {
    a=ArrayNew(1);
    ArrayAppend(a, arguments.oid);
    ArrayAppend(a, arguments.zipcode);
    return a;
}

function newKeyValue(key, value) {
    s=StructNew();
    s["Key"]=arguments.key;
    s["Value"]=arguments.value;
    return s;
}
</cfscript>


<cftry>

<cfscript>
ws = CreateObject("webservice", "http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/services/Locators/TA_Address_NA_10/GeocodeServer?wsdl");
recordset=StructNew();
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#ws#" label="#GetCurrentTemplatePath()#" />

<h1>GeocodeAddresses</h1>
<cfscript>
fields=ArrayNew(1);
ArrayAppend(fields, newField("zipcode", "esriFieldTypeString", true, 10, 0, 0));
ArrayAppend(fields, newField("oid", "esriFieldTypeOID", false, 10, 0, 0));
recordset["Fields"]=fields;

records=ArrayNew(1);
ArrayAppend(records, newRecord(1,"90210"));
recordset["Records"]=records;


mappings=ArrayNew(1);
ArrayAppend(mappings, newKeyValue("zipcode", "Zip"));
</cfscript>

<cfdump var="#recordSet#" label="#GetCurrentTemplatePath()#" />
<cfdump var="#mappings#" label="#GetCurrentTemplatePath()#" />

<cfscript>
result = ws.geocodeAddresses(recordSet, mappings, JavaCast("null", ""));
</cfscript>

<cfdump var="#ws#" label="#GetCurrentTemplatePath()#" />

<cfcatch>
    <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" label="#GetCurrentTemplatePath()#" />
</cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a really good place to get started with consuming complex datatypes with Coldfusion. They can be very tricky since you may need an array, an array of structs or a simple struct depending on item the WSDL.

http://tjordahl.blogspot.com/2008/04/reprint-consuming-web-service-complex.html (don't discard it because it's old - the information is still relevant event for CF9)

Generally, if there is more than one item, you will need to create an array, otherwise it's a struct.  I've found you need to user str['key'] rather than str.key or str = {key=value} for structures since case sensitivity is only maintained with the first convention.

In my experience, it takes a lot of trial and error, especially if you have several items you are passing into the request.

Comment: This seems relevant, though I don't quite understand how to apply it, I have edited the question.  Any single line change you could show me to understand it better?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't had time to dig in too deeply, but you may want to try an array of structs rather than struct of arrays, so in looking at the "fields" variable, try fields = [{}]. 

Also, I would grab SOAP UI and play with it to help understand what the request should look like. I've found it an invaluable tool.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mirror the complex data type with CFC, see:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7dbf.html

Comment: This seems to be about using CFC's to define complexTypes for your own web service.  Does this apply as well for calling a web service?

Comment: Look like I'll have to give it a shot then.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't match up.  I ge the error Web service operation geocodeAddresses with parameters {[(Component=com.esri.www.schemas.ArcGIS._10_0.recordset)],[(Component=com.esri.www.schemas.ArcGIS._10_0.PropertySet)],[(Component=com.esri.www.schemas.ArcGIS._10_0.PropertySet)]} cannot be found.

Comment: Maybe you can contact @ShirakAvakian http://twitter.com/#!/ShirakAvakian/status/45326021548974080

Comment: I think that I may just need to create these classes in Java.